# pagination header for dynamic website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I have a concern and I'm still not able to sort it out until now.
I'd like to create seo pagination for website's results page, and have it into the html header.
The problem is, I'm not really able to do it as the previous developer choose to use javascript: void(0) instead. I'd like to change it.
Here is the current code:

```
$total_page = ceil($total/$perpage);
$startpoint = ($page * $perpage) - $perpage;
$lim = 5;
$link = 'javascript:void(0);';
$pdata = '<div class="pg2_pagnation" style="float:right">'.pagination_front($page,$total_page,$link,$lim).'</div>';
```

The output of the page is:

123 Next    or   Previous 12345 Next. (While having the cursor on the pagination, the shows javascript:void(0))
However, I'm facing some issues with my javascript, so, would prefer to avoid that and to have a proper link on the pagination.
I'd like to better have some thing like: http:www.example/cars/page1, http:www.example/cars/page2, http:www.example/cars/page3, ... http:www.example/cars/page10 (last page) instead.

Also, regarding the header, I'd like to use the pagination for some seo purposes and have:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/page1">
<link rel="prev" href="https://www.example.com/page2">
<link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/page4">
```

Thanks in advance for your time and your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

These pagination links are JavaScript ones, what means the script probably does asynchronous call to the server when a link is clicked and dynamically replaces current list of items.

Find the JavaScript code, find out what exactly it does (eg. it calls  https://www.example.com/data_for_page_4 to get the data) and build links from that requests. You might need to adjust the content you receive from such request.

Comment: Is that possible to change and it without the JavaScript call? JavaScript is where my problem is actually, as I doesn't provide the result expected, and I can't really find where is the exact problem, that why, I rather prefer to code it without the calling of JavaScript

Comment: Yes it is possible, that is what I meant - to look into JS, rewrite HTML/PHP and delete the JS